# External mouse plugin causing browser re-render of page in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, browser

Basic problem: plugging in an external mouse causes both chrome and firefox to add scrollbars to a page (that I built) in my browser. I'm trying to figure out why this is, but having a hard time finding information. We've tested and reproduced the problem on OSX 10.7.5 and 10.8.5.

My theory is that since both browsers are responding in this manner, the sequence of events is something like:

1. plug in external mouse.
2. The OS recognizes the mouse and sends some sort of event to running applications.
3. The running applications receive this event, and change the rendering of the page.

I've diffed the computed styles of both states, and there is no difference, just to rule it out. Here's an animated gif of what's happening. the only thing I'm doing to trigger the change is plugging in an external mouse:

[image]

My question is, what kind of event is sent from the OS to the browser when an external mouse is plugged in, and how do I dig deeper into how that event is being dealt with?

Comment: What the...heck?! I've never seen anything like this. What kind of sorcery is this. Also, could you post a fiddle with markup and styling that makes this scrollbar appear? I think it has something to do with the browser's default stryling shifting from mobile to desktop with the external mouse.

Comment: What's the code of your site like? If you've got some responsive design, then OptimusCrime's idea could make sense.

Comment: our app is pretty involved, and I've found it hard to extract an example. we are using flexbox for responsive layout.

Comment: i just experienced the same thing. I am using a Logitch mouse with USB-dongle instead of an Apple mouse — scrollbars everywhere. my webapp uses CSS where some object is position from the right, when the scrollbars are visible, the object position is shifted.

Comment: i just experienced the same thing. I am using a Logitch mouse with USB-dongle instead of an Apple mouse — scrollbars everywhere.

Comment: This is still an issue (5 years later) ! Have a look on https://fullcalendar.io/#demos (click the resource timeline demo) and plug in your mouse and out again - notice that the top resource in the list will be hidden if the external mouse is not plugged in

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I’m not totally misunderstanding your problem, then this has nothing to do with the browser, but rather is a feature of OS X to hide the scrollbars (in every supported program) as long as you’re using an input device that doesn’t need scrollbars (like a MacBook’s trackpad). If this is the case, then the scrollbars should also appear in e.g. Finder with your mouse plugged in.

To change this behavior, go to `System Preferences` > `General` and select `Always` under `Show scroll bars`.

Comment: You can also choose `When scrolling` to not show the scroll bars even when the external mouse is plugged in.

Comment: Thanks for this. I was losing my mind trying to figure out why the scrollbar behavior was changing when I was using just my macbook compared to when I was plugged in at my workstation w/mouse, keyboard, and monitors.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was that using vw units don't take into consideration the scrollbar width. Changing our CSS to use % instead of vw works (50% vs 50vw).

CanIUse.com says:

> Currently all browsers but Firefox incorrectly consider 100vw to be
>   the entire page width, including vertical scroll bar, which can cause
>   a horizontal scroll bar when overflow: auto is set.

- http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

See this codepen for proof. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGYNWZ try with and without USB Mouse.

CSS:

```
:root, html {
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.thing {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 110vh;
  background: blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="thing">

</div>
```